# Issue with NetworkCallbackDelegate

Tags: c#, callback, fivem

I'm searching to get some players infos from a database with events in C#.

When I try my script in game, this error message appears :

```
[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/ System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/ 

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/ 

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/ Server stack trace: 

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/   at CitizenFX.Core.InternalManager.PrintError (System.String where, System.Exception what) [0x00081] in C:\gl\builds\master\fivem\code\client\clrcore\InternalManager.cs:595 

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/   at CitizenFX.Core.InternalManager.CallRef (System.Int32 refIndex, System.Byte[] argsSerialized, System.IntPtr& retvalSerialized, System.Int32& retvalSize) [0x000b6] in C:\gl\builds\master\fivem\code\client\clrcore\InternalManager.cs:527 

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) CitizenFX.Core.InternalManager:CallRef (int,byte[],intptr&,int&)

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/   at (wrapper xdomain-dispatch) CitizenFX.Core.InternalManager:CallRef (object,byte[]&,byte[]&,int,byte[],int&)

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/ 

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/ Exception rethrown at [0]: 

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/   at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) CitizenFX.Core.InternalManager:CallRef (int,byte[],intptr&,int&)

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) CitizenFX.Core.InternalManager:CallRef (int,byte[],intptr&,int&)

[   9419687] [b2699_GTAProce]             MainThrd/   at CitizenFX.Core.MonoScriptRuntime.CallRef (System.Int32 refIndex, System.Byte[] argsSerialized, System.Int32 argsSize, System.IntPtr& retvalSerialized, System.Int32& retvalSize) [0x00013] in C:\gl\builds\master\fivem\code\client\clrcore\MonoScriptRuntime.cs:228
```

If you want to see it, here is my two scripts, the first is in the client side, the second one is in the server side.

Client-side :

```c
public void GetPlayerInformations()
    {
        TriggerServerEvent("MST_SV_GetInformationOfPlayer",new Action <string, int, string>((userId, department, callsign) =>
        {
            _Functions.SendTextToConsole(Functions.InfoType.Debug, $"UserId: {userId} | Department: {department} | Callsign: {callsign}");
            if (userId != null)
            {
                UserId = userId;
                Department = department;
                Callsign = callsign;
            }
        }));
    }
```

Server-side :

```c
private static void GetInformationOfPlayer([FromSource] Player player, NetworkCallbackDelegate callback)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection())
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command = connection.GetCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "select * from user where license = @identifier";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identifier", player.Identifiers["license"]);
                    using (DbDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (result.Read())
                        {
                            _functions.SendTextToConsole(Functions.InfoType.Debug,$"License : {result["license"]}, Department : {result["department"]}, Callsign : {result["callsign"]}.");
                            callback.Invoke(Convert.ToString(result["license"]), Convert.ToInt32(result["department"]), Convert.ToString(result["callsign"]));
                            _functions.SendTextToConsole(Functions.InfoType.Info, $"Informations of player {player.Name} has been loaded successfully.");
                            result.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Other part of the script non related to my issue
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            _functions.SendTextToConsole(Functions.InfoType.Error, $"An error has occurred while loading informations of player {player.Name} : {e.Message}");
        }
    }
```

I already check the database connection (it is okay), differents variables types, and the three variables gave through the callback aren't null (checked with the Debug.WriteLine) ...